# Executing code/script during windows startup repair

Tags: c++, c, windows, boot, repair

My question sounds pretty simple, but the answer to it is very difficult for me to find myself.
The question is as follows: **Is it possible to somehow execute your code / script during the execution of Windows Automatic Repair? If so, how.**

Comment: I voted to migrate your question to [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions), where I think it is much better suited. If you want to speed up the process delete the question here and post it there.

Comment: Disagree with migration. The C and C++ tags, as well as "execute code" make it clear that this is a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. You're looking for the *Windows Recovery Environment*, and you can [add tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-a-custom-tool-to-the-windows-re-boot-options-menu) to that environment.

The basic steps involve:

1. Create an XML file describing your tool
2. Add the tool and its XML to the Recovery Image (WinRE.wim)
3. Add the tool to the Recovery boot menu